# change the pop-up image width and height in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm trying to change change the pop-up image width and height in fancybox but i'm being unsuccessful, i'm not sure what to change in the jquery.fancybox.css. Any help?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/5191/

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to add a more specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: @NathanTuggy i edit it a bit, but i'm not sure what is it exactly you want. I just haven't been able to edit the pop-up image width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it computes dynamically based on the screen size.  However, you could try adjusting the `.fancybox-image` class.  Also check the `.fancybox-outer` and `.fancybox-inner` classes.  You might have to adjust them too.

Comment: are you still online?

Comment: yes. I'm still online.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer and doesn't provide a solution to the problem but suggesting possibilities

Comment: @JFK: I assume the OP knows how to edit css classes (which is basic knowledge if you are into webdesign).  The `fancybox-image` is what defines the element.  The other classes as suggested to be checked because they have the tendency to change the properties while being displayed.  I used suggestive words because we don't know the exact environment the OP is working on.  It is for the OP to try and solve his problem based on the direction given.  Solutions do not always need code to be put, rather to show the direction that solves the problem (which it did in this case).  :-)